# How do I integrate Dropbox in Sync Menu Indicator?

Tags: indicator, sync, cloud, dropbox

Is there anyway to integrate Dropbox in the Sync (cloud) Menu Indicator?

Comment: Bug is posted here as of 10/21/13 for 13.10. Looks like they are working on it.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sync/+bug/1096934

Answer (score 4):

I just tried installing it, but it just crashed when I tried starting it.

But you could always try asking the developers [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sync/+questions) or file a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sync).

Comment: [Bug filled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sync/+bug/1096934), just say *[this bug affects me too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sync/+bug/1096934/+affectsmetoo)*...